# Missing cordova_plugins.json error when/testing in browser

Tags: json, plugins, cordova

I am using Phonegap to develop a phone app  and I have to be honest, I'm a little stumped.

I get a 404 error about cordova_plugin.json when I test/view the app

Could someone please let me know what this is and how I can fix this error.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version less than 3.0, you can ignore this error, or create an empty cordova-plugin.json file with just {} inside. You could also edit the JavaScript code, see here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3029?focusedCommentId=13647590&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13647590

Comment: I did it but it does not work.probably the problem is in the emulator,  What Emulator would you recommend? I use the real Emulator for Android (5554:Galaxy). Windows8

Comment: Sorry, I usually only use a physical device. If I have to use an emulator it is usually whichever one is bundled with eclipse. Did you try to edit the code like in the link that I pasted?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand your question. This error happens because in 3.0 Cordova JS reads the plugin.json file to see where the JS files are for each plugin. The code to read the json file was introduced in 2.9 but wasn't needed, which is why you can ignore the error message in 2.9